# Why KL divergence is giving nan? Is it some mathematical error or my input data is incorrect?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

In the following code s returns nan. As each value in Q<1 so it returns a negative value when I take its log. Does it mean that I can not calculate KL divergence with these values of P and Q or can I fix it?

```
`P= np.array([1.125,3.314,2.7414]) 
Q=np.array([0.42369288, 0.89152044, 0.60905852])

for i in range(len(P)):
    if P[i] != 0 and Q[i]!=0:
        s= P[i] *np.log(P[i]/Q[i])
        print("s: ",s)`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of, `P` and `Q` should describe probability mass functions, meaning that each element should be in the interval `[0,1]` and they each should sum to `1`, which is not the case for your examples.

The second `np.log` is wrong. Is there a reason you put it there or was it a typo? It should be `P[i]*np.log(P[i]/Q[i])`. You also want to perform the sum over all these terms for `i`.

Finally there is a technical issue of what to do if `P[i] = 0`. In that case `np.log(0)` would cause problems. The actual contribution of the term should be `0` in that case (because `lim_{x->0} x*log(x) = 0`). You can guarantee this, e.g. by handling this case specially with an `if` clause.

The case of `Q[i] = 0` would cause similar issues, however the KL divergence doesn't exist if `Q[i] = 0`, but not `P[i] = 0`, anyway.

Comment: I plotted histogram using hist,bin_edges,patches=plt,hist(x,bins=10,density=True).  So hist returned me 10 values which represent y-axis values of histogram. I used these values as Q. They are not adding up to 1. However, hist*np.diff(bin_edges) =1. which is the area under the curve. For the sake of simplicity I mentioned only 3 values. I you want to see I can edit my question. Secondly log in the denominator was typo mistake. Do you think that my input is incorrect?

Comment: If you you resolved all the issues I mentioned, as it seems from your comment, then I don't see any problem with your code, besides the `0` value problem, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: So I need to mention a condition that if P[i] !=0 and Q[i]!=0. right? Secondly you mentioned about Probability mass function which demands area under curve =1 but you mention that P and Q should sum to 1. Only histogram's y axis values can not add up to 1. I'm littile confused why you mentioned this